# After update android studio all old flutter project not run

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I get below error when i try to run app

Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/user/Desktop/Ridham/e_commerce/Desi_Chicken/DesiChiken_Vendor/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/8.0.2/scripts/df7u4no3ok2toy60b1rh7yy2p).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 65

```
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/user/Desktop/Ridham/e_commerce/Desi_Chicken/DesiChiken_Vendor/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/8.0.2/scripts/df7u4no3ok2toy60b1rh7yy2p).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` in your project and update the distribution URL to match the gradle version that supports your Java version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

rebuild gradle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe deleting `/Users/user/.gradle/caches` folder will solve your issue.

Comment: I am using mac system